# NSIS - CopyFiles Directive not working with variables as parameters?

Tags: nsis

I want to copy files/folders from one folder of enduser-system to another folder of enduser-system.
However the CopyFiles directive seems to be not working, when passing variables like $0, $1 as source parameter..

```
...
SetRegView 64
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "${PRODUCT_HOME_ROOT}\$1" "License"
MessageBox MB_OK "$0"     
CreateDirectory '"$INSTDIR\application\license"'
CopyFiles "$0" "$INSTDIR\application\license"
```

The string stored in $0 is checked, and is identical to the absolute path of the file.
If i pass the source parameter as "C:\path_to_folder", the CopyFiles directive is working, as expected.
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: also tried to store the variable value in another variable via `!define` directive,.. also not working,.. also using `*.*` in `CopyFiles "$0\*.*" ...` doesnt work

Comment: What does the messagebox display for "$0"?

Comment: it displays "C:\Program Files\DevApp\0.1.0.0\application\license" (the quotes belong to the output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable should work but the actual string stored in that variable should not be double quoted and it should only use backslashes (`\`), not forward slashes (`/`).

```
Section
InitPluginsDir
CreateDirectory "$PluginsDir\Src"
File "/oname=$PluginsDir\Src\test.txt" "${__FILE__}"
CreateDirectory "$PluginsDir\Dst"
StrCpy $0 "$PluginsDir\Src\test.txt"
CopyFiles "$0" "$PluginsDir\Dst"
ExecShell explore "$PluginsDir\Dst"
MessageBox MB_OK "Done?"
Quit
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Your provided example didnt worked for me, as File only allows to set one specific file. But your explanation about slashes gave me the clue. It seems that reading from registry entries, returns the string quoted. However, with use of [CharStrip](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/CharStrip_%26_StrStrip:_Remove_character_or_string_from_another_string) I managed to remove the quotes from the string and pass that argument to CopyFiles. It works now for me!

Comment: My example worked when I tried it, does not really matter though, I added it only to show that variables work with CopyFiles.